# odd IE9 with xml, php, curl

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a php function that communicates with UPS using curl, xml.The script was given to me and i dont know much about it.

It works in every browser except IE9

The function returns something like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 21:36:41 GMT Server: Apache
>   Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 1481 X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5
>   JSP/2.1 Vary: User-Agent Content-Type: application/xml

it goes on to show all the responses 
 from ups in xml

here is the function with the curl and xml parameters.

```
function ups($dest_zip,$service,$weight,$length,$width,$height) {

        // This script was written by Mark Sanborn at http://www.marksanborn.net
        // If this script benefits you are your business please consider a donation
        // You can donate at http://www.marksanborn.net/donate.

        // ========== CHANGE THESE VALUES TO MATCH YOUR OWN ===========

          $AccessLicenseNumber = '000000009F002AC0'; // Your license number <br>
          $UserId = '+++++'; // Username <br>
          $Password = '+++++'; // Password <br>
          $PostalCode = '01862'; // Zipcode you are shipping FROM <br>
          $ShipperNumber = '++++'; // Your UPS shipper number <br>

        // =============== DON'T CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE ===============


            $data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
            <AccessRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">
                <AccessLicenseNumber>$AccessLicenseNumber</AccessLicenseNumber>
                <UserId>$UserId</UserId>
                <Password>$Password</Password>
            </AccessRequest>
            <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
            <RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">
                <Request>
                    <TransactionReference>
                        <CustomerContext>Bare Bones Rate Request</CustomerContext>
                        <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>
                    </TransactionReference>
                    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
                    <RequestOption>Rate</RequestOption>
                </Request>
            <PickupType>
                <Code>01</Code>
            </PickupType>
            <Shipment>
                <Shipper>
                    <Address>
                        <PostalCode>$PostalCode</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    </Address>
                <ShipperNumber>$ShipperNumber</ShipperNumber>
                </Shipper>
                <ShipTo>
                    <Address>
                        <PostalCode>$dest_zip</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    <ResidentialAddressIndicator/>
                    </Address>
                </ShipTo>
                <ShipFrom>
                    <Address>
                        <PostalCode>$PostalCode</PostalCode>
                        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                    </Address>
                </ShipFrom>
                <Service>
                    <Code>$service</Code>
                </Service>
                <Package>
                    <PackagingType>
                        <Code>02</Code>
                    </PackagingType>
                    <Dimensions>
                        <UnitOfMeasurement>
                            <Code>IN</Code>
                        </UnitOfMeasurement>
                        <Length>$length</Length>
                        <Width>$width</Width>
                        <Height>$height</Height>
                    </Dimensions>
                    <PackageWeight>
                        <UnitOfMeasurement>
                            <Code>LBS</Code>
                        </UnitOfMeasurement>
                        <Weight>$weight</Weight>
                    </PackageWeight>
                </Package>
            </Shipment>
            </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>";
            $ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate");
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,0);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
            $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        echo '<!-- '. $result. ' -->'; // THIS LINE IS FOR DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY-IT WILL SHOW IN HTML COMMENTS
            $data = strstr($result, '<?');
            $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
            xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
            xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
            $params = array();
            $level = array();
            foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
             if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
            if (array_key_exists('attributes',$xml_elem)) {
                 list($level[$xml_elem['level']],$extra) = array_values($xml_elem['attributes']);
            } else {
                 $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
            }
             }
             if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
            $start_level = 1;
            $php_stmt = '$params';
            while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
                 $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
                 $start_level++;
            }
            //$php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
            if (isset($xml_elem['value'])) {
                $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
                }
                else {
                $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = "";';
                }

            eval($php_stmt);
             }
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $params['RATINGSERVICESELECTIONRESPONSE']['RATEDSHIPMENT']['TOTALCHARGES']['MONETARYVALUE'];
        }
```

The page will not render the HTML

I have no clue what I am doing. HELP!

Comment: Try using HTML4... no, just trolling. Paste some code, or link. Try sending `Content-Type: text/html` via PHP...

Comment: Found it!!!! it was the echo statement.... DOH!!! Thanks to everyone that helped me.. +1 all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that the output of headers hasn't been enabled

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
```

Comment out that line or set it to false.

Comment: thanks for the response   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); do i set to 0 then?

Comment: Without knowing if the code needs the header information as part of its processing, try setting it to 0 and seeing what the outcome is. Generaly this is the kind of option that isn't used unless there's a specific reason for it (eg fetching cookie information or location redirects)

Comment: thanks scuzzy: i set to 0 and tried to comment out, it fails to render the html.. should i be using include when referencing the function? or something else?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more code to understand what the curl process is doing. Somewhere there will be the responds of the CURL request dumped into a variable like $curl_result = curl_exec ($curl_handle); which is probably either being echoed prematurely or there's some processing that's not correct.

Comment: Again, thanks for taking the time. I added the actual function in its entirety.

Comment: I include(ups_function.php) and call it in the php by $var = ups($variables)

Comment: Indeed, I just saw line for "THIS LINE IS FOR DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY-IT WILL SHOW IN HTML COMMENTS"